# What does "to put one's feet to sleep" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

The [Wall Street](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094291/) (1987) movie features the following line from [Gordon Gekko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gordon_Gekko) (played by actor [Michael Douglas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Douglas)) around 00:53:30 ([YouTube](https://youtu.be/dwEXuGp6TkA)):

> My wife tells me you made a move on Darien. Here's some inside info for ya. That Euroflash GQ type she's going with? He's got big bucks, but he's **putting her feet to sleep**. *Exit visas* are imminent. I don't want you to lose your place in line.

I can roughly understand the idea from the context, but what exactly does the expression "*to put one's feet to sleep*" mean, and when it can be used?

Comment: @Clare That's exactly the point here (except it's compression of the nerves rather than blood vessels that causes it): Darien is bored by Sir Lawrence, and a breakup ('exit visas') is imminent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When someone says a limb is "asleep", it means that the part is experiencing [transient paresthesia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paresthesia) caused by prolonged pressure on a nerve.  Often sitting or sleeping in an unusual way will cause this problem.

In the scene, Gecko is telling Bud that Darien, a woman he is interesting in, is dating another man, but is bored by him (he is "putting her feet to sleep"), and so Bud still has a chance.

It's not really idiomatic, but then, Oliver Stone was never very good at writing dialog.

Comment: +1 And "exit visas are imminent" means that she's about to end the relationship.

Comment: @StoneyB -- another example of poor writing, though: a exit visa is a permit to leave.  What is imminent would be a metaphorical deportation order, a requirement he leave.

Comment: I'm not convinced it's a reference to the medical condition you speak of.  If it is so not idiomatic, then maybe it refers to  something else.